# Visual Studio 2015, compress codeblock to one-liner?

Tags: visual-studio, coding-style, visual-studio-2015

Is there any shortcut/command to compress an existing block of code to a single line in Visual Studio? I have version 2015.

I want to "compress" from this:

```
public string DatePart
{
    get
    {
        return _match.Groups[1].Value;
    }
}
```

to this:

```
public string DatePart { get { return _match.Groups[1].Value; } }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but hope this helps.

Not in VS. Just make sure you have under tools->Text Editor->your language Wrapping leave blocks on single line is selected.

Also, you can use this tool: Code Maid

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496